# "Operating system not found" after hard reset on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: data-recovery, ubuntu-16.04

My ubuntu 16.04 install was broken by a hard reset. I do not think it is a disk failure because I am now able to mount my partition and read my files from a bootable USB. (I had to run fsck because it was giving me "bad superblock" errors.) Also, the "check disk for errors" option in GRUB on my bootable USB doesn't report any problems.

When I try to boot, I see "PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable". Then, it displays "operating system not found" and stops trying to boot.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

I had to run the Boot-Repair tool from a live usb with the option to reinstall grub enabled.